# JavaScript Array of objects to a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an array of objects which was fetched from a **JSON** `(JSONP)` file using jQuery.

I'm required to display this data using an HTML dropdown.

Current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $.getJSON('remote-json-proxy.php?lang=en&callback=?', function(data){

    console.log(data);


    })
</script>
```

How do I put this `data` variable which is array of objects to be displayed using HTML drop-down?

object array looks like this

```
Object
 lines: Array[10]
0: Object
   line: "COLOMBO - BADULLA"
 1: Object
 2: Object
 3: Object
 4: Object
 5: Object
 6: Object
 7: Object
```

**JSON File**

```
( {"lines":[{"line":"COLOMBO - BADULLA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - MATALE"},{"line":"COLOMBO - PUTTLAM"},{"line":"COLOMBO - THANDIKULAM"},{"line":"COLOMBO - TALAIMANNAR"},{"line":"COLOMBO - BATTICALOA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - TRINCOMALEE"},{"line":"COLOMBO - MATARA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - AVISSAWELLA"},{"line":"COLOMBO - MIHINTALE"}]} );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oDDL = $("<select>");
    $.getJSON('remote-json-proxy.php?lang=en&callback=?', function(data) {
        $.each(data.lines, function(i, item) {
            oDDL.append('<option>' + item.line + '</option>');
        });
    });
    $("body").append(oDDL);
});
```

As you can see, it's building drop down list object and appending `options` to it for every item in the JSON array.

**Note:** Each JSON response is different, the `data.lines` and `item.line` match the JSON format of this specific case only.

Comment: What exactly `remote-json-proxy.php` is returning? Can you post example?

Comment: hi i have updated the question with details check it , thanks :-)

Comment: Try changing `data.items` to be `data.lines` then.

Comment: what should i give here ?  `oDDL.append('<option>' + item.d.title + '</option>');` for **title** ?

Comment: Change `item.d.title` to just `item.line` or `item.d.line` I'm not sure how exactly JSON works in this context..

Comment: Cheers, I've also edited my answer to have the correct code and a note to others with different JSON format.

Comment: cool thanks a lot for the help was trying to figure this out from yesterday ! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You'd first have to create a  element in your html if you don't have one:

```
<select id='myselect'></select>
```

Then, in your js, assuming you have properties `.value` y `.caption` per item you would do:

```
$.getJSON('remote-json-proxy.php?lang=en&callback=?', function(data){
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){ //Traverse the data array
       var value = data[i].value;
       var text = data[i].caption;
       $('<option/>').val(value).text(text).appendTo('#myselect');
    };
});
```

Just that. Hope this helps. Cheers